# LinkedList without dynamic memory allocation

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, static

Lets imagine that we are using development environment without dynamic memory (there are only static arrays with fixed bounds). How could one implement List (or ArrayList).
Well, I have idea of just cretaing new array of bigger size when I'm trying to add element to a full array, but I hope there is more efficient way.
P.S I'm not asking for implementation, I'm asking for ideas :)

Comment: A common trick is to recreate the list if it's full. Not with just one element, but a lot, anticipating of size growth. In this way you'll have only a small performance impact if the upperbound is reached. ... oh wait... that's what you suggested :-)

Comment: An alternative is to create one container for all possible type and create the largest possible list for that container (or a couple). You'll then be able to create sub-lists from that big array and the type is defined in that container. A bit like the old `VARIANT` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) container. It will give you speed over memory, but usualy this isn't worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check  Sedgewick's document about dynamic arrays and resizing them. You can see the general idea in [Dynamic Array - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) and a more detailed definition in [this paper which is written by Sedgewick](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1999/09/CS-99-09.pdf)
Also there is a sample in [ResizingArrayQueue by Sedgewick](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/ResizingArrayQueue.java.html)

Although, the example is used for the queues you can use this mechanism also for linkedlists.
In this sample he is doubling the size when it reaches the limit.

```
public void enqueue(Item item) {
        // double size of array if necessary and recopy to front of array
        if (N == q.length) resize(2*q.length);   // double size of array if necessary
        q[last++] = item;                        // add item
        if (last == q.length) last = 0;          // wrap-around
        N++;
    }
```

And when the limit decreases to the quarter of the array, he is halving the array.

```
 public Item dequeue() {
        if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue underflow");
        Item item = q[first];
        q[first] = null;                            // to avoid loitering
        N--;
        first++;
        if (first == q.length) first = 0;           // wrap-around
        // shrink size of array if necessary
        if (N > 0 && N == q.length/4) resize(q.length/2); 
        return item;
    }
```